# How to move the text to the top slightly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I am trying to design a slider, To display a title and little details below with a link to direct to the details of the title, I am trying to do this task with CSS and HTML. here's the HTML file:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Monoton|Poiret+One|Raleway");
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.75vw;
}

body * {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  height: 25vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider>ul {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.slider>ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 2000ms ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-0:checked~ul>li.slide-0,
.slider>#input-slide-1:checked~ul>li.slide-1,
.slider>#input-slide-2:checked~ul>li.slide-2,
.slider>#input-slide-3:checked~ul>li.slide-3 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider>ul>li.slide-0 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}

.slider>ul>li.slide-1 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}

.slider>ul>li.slide-2 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}

.slider>ul>li.slide-3 {
  background-color: #47d7ed;
}

.slider>.slider-dot {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -4vw;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 300;
  font-size: 0;
}

.slider>.slider-dot>label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1vw 0.5vw;
  width: 1vw;
  height: 1vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.slider>#input-slide-0:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-0,
.slider>#input-slide-1:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-1,
.slider>#input-slide-2:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-2,
.slider>#input-slide-3:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-3 {
  background-color: black;
}

.slider>.slider-dot>label:hover {
  background-color: #f73c3f !important;
}

.slider>.slide-description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 3vw);
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.slider>.slide-description>label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-0:checked~.slide-description>.slide-0,
.slider>#input-slide-1:checked~.slide-description>.slide-1,
.slider>#input-slide-2:checked~.slide-description>.slide-2,
.slider>#input-slide-3:checked~.slide-description>.slide-3 {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slider>.slide-description>label>.text-slide {
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 6vw;
  top: 0px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6%,
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  30%,
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~ul>li.slide-0 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite -2000ms linear;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~ul>li.slide-1 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 6000ms linear;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~ul>li.slide-2 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 14000ms linear;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~ul>li.slide-3 {
  animation: slide 32000ms infinite 22000ms linear;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~ul>li {
  transition: none;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0%,
  24% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes dot {
  0%,
  24% {
    background-color: #333;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-0 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite -2000ms;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-1 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 6000ms;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-2 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 14000ms;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slider-dot>label.slide-3 {
  animation: dot 32000ms infinite 22000ms;
}

@keyframes description {
  0%,
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  6%,
  24% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slide-description>.slide-0 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite -2000ms ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slide-description>.slide-1 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 6000ms ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slide-description>.slide-2 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 14000ms ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slide-description>.slide-3 {
  animation: description 32000ms infinite 22000ms ease;
}

.slider>#input-slide-autoplay:checked~.slide-description>label {
  transition: none;
}

.readmorebutton {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #C10E0E;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-0" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
  <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-1" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
  <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-2" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
  <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-3" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
  <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-autoplay" type="radio" class="input-slide" checked />
  <ul>
    <li class="slide-0"></li>
    <li class="slide-1"></li>
    <li class="slide-2"></li>
    <li class="slide-3"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slide-description">
    <label class="slide-0">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
                    <a href="{% url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
                </label>
    <label class="slide-1">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #2</h1>
                </label>
    <label class="slide-2">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #3</h1>
                </label>
    <label class="slide-3">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #4</h1>
                </label>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-dot">
    <label class="slide-0" for="input-slide-0"></label>
    <label class="slide-1" for="input-slide-1"></label>
    <label class="slide-2" for="input-slide-2"></label>
    <label class="slide-3" for="input-slide-3"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

With all of the above CODE I am getting this output:-
[image]

I am trying to move the `H1`, `h5`, and the `a` section to slightly above compared to the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lowered the top value in CSS.

```
.slider > .slide-description { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%; 
  top: calc(35% - 3vw); //===> you can adjust the top position according to your needs here
  left: 25%; 
  z-index: 200; 
}
```

**Complete code:**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Monoton|Poiret+One|Raleway");
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.75vw;
}
body * {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
}
ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    display: none;
}

.slider {
    height: 25vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider > ul {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.slider > ul > li {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 2000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ ul > li.slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ ul > li.slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ ul > li.slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ ul > li.slide-3 {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-0 {
    background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-1 {
    background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-2 {
    background-color: #47d7ed;
}
.slider > ul > li.slide-3 {
    background-color: #47d7ed;
}


.slider > .slider-dot {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -4vw;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 300;
    font-size: 0;
}
.slider > .slider-dot > label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1vw 0.5vw;
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    border-radius: 50%;

    background-color: #fff;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-3 {
    background-color: black;
}
.slider > .slider-dot > label:hover {
    background-color: #f73c3f !important;
}
.slider > .slide-description {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: calc(35% - 3vw);
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 200;
}
.slider > .slide-description > label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;

    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.75s ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-0:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-0,
.slider > #input-slide-1:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-1,
.slider > #input-slide-2:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-2,
.slider > #input-slide-3:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-3 {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.slider > .slide-description > label > .text-slide {
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 6vw;
    top: 0px;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    6%,
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    30%,
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-0 {
    animation: slide 32000ms infinite -2000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-1 {
    animation: slide 32000ms infinite 6000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-2 {
    animation: slide 32000ms infinite 14000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li.slide-3 {
    animation: slide 32000ms infinite 22000ms linear;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ ul > li {
    transition: none;
}

@keyframes arrow {
    0%,
    24% {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    25%,
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
    }
}

@keyframes dot {
    0%,
    24% {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    25%,
    100% {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-0 {
    animation: dot 32000ms infinite -2000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-1 {
    animation: dot 32000ms infinite 6000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-2 {
    animation: dot 32000ms infinite 14000ms;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slider-dot > label.slide-3 {
    animation: dot 32000ms infinite 22000ms;
}

@keyframes description {
    0%,
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    6%,
    24% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    25%,
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-0 {
    animation: description 32000ms infinite -2000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-1 {
    animation: description 32000ms infinite 6000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-2 {
    animation: description 32000ms infinite 14000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > .slide-3 {
    animation: description 32000ms infinite 22000ms ease;
}
.slider > #input-slide-autoplay:checked ~ .slide-description > label {
    transition: none;
}

.readmorebutton{
    padding: 5px 15px; 
    color:#fff; 
    background-color: #C10E0E; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 4px 0; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Trying</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-0" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
            <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-1" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
            <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-2" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
            <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-3" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" />
            <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-autoplay" type="radio" class="input-slide" checked />
            <ul>
                <li class="slide-0"></li>
                <li class="slide-1"></li>
                <li class="slide-2"></li>
                <li class="slide-3"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="slide-description">
                <label class="slide-0">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h5>
                    <a href="{% url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
                </label>
                <label class="slide-1">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #2</h1>
                </label>
                <label class="slide-2">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #3</h1>
                </label>
                <label class="slide-3">
                    <h1 class="text-slide">CSS SLIDER #4</h1>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-dot">
                <label class="slide-0" for="input-slide-0"></label>
                <label class="slide-1" for="input-slide-1"></label>
                <label class="slide-2" for="input-slide-2"></label>
                <label class="slide-3" for="input-slide-3"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the right answer, but could you point out what you changed specifically. Kind of hard to spot since it is in the middle of that big blob of CSS. Specifically, it was the `top` value in the `.slider > .slide-description` selector, just shy of half of way.

Comment: .slider > .slide-description {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: calc(35% - 3vw);
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 200;
}  top is getting calculated here so you can adjust it according to your needs.